# d3 count data (votes) and store it for use

Tags: javascript

I have voting data from 2000 people. Each line contains a sequence of votes, each for one of two options (or neither). I'm trying to condense this data into the total number of votes per subject.

I have a [CSV file](http://www.sfu.ca/~djr7/data/) that looks like this:

```
 A         C         F
 B         C         E
 A         D         E
```

The first column is a vote between `A` and `B`, the second column between `C` and `D`.

Comment: I posted an answer below. Tell me whether I parsed the data according to your specifications.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```js
var parse = function (url) {
    getCSV(url, function (err, data) {
        // split the data by line, then split each line by commas
        data = data.split("\n").map(function (line) { return line.split(",") });
        // we want to ignore the first two elements since they're junk
        var mapping = groupOptions(data[0].slice(2));
        // skip the first line, since it isn't a vote
        data.slice(1).forEach(function (line) {
            // skip the first two elements of each line
            // then go through each "vote"
            line.slice(2).forEach(function (vote, i) {
                // if `mapping[i][0]` (our record of votes) equals `vote`, record it
                if (mapping[i][0].name == vote) {
                    mapping[i][0].number += 1;
                // also explicitly check whether the other option was voted for
                // since voting is optional
                } else if (mapping[i][1].name == vote){
                    mapping[i][1].number += 1;
                }
            })
        })
        console.log(mapping);
        return mapping;
    });
}
var groupOptions = function (options) {
    // this function will be fed an array of strings:
    // ["A or B", "C or D", ... ]
    // we want to reduce this to a single mapping
    return options.reduce(function (p, c) {
        // split the current array element at " or " (to get both options)
        var holder = c.split(" or ");
        // now push an array of two objects, each representing the different options
        p.push([{ name: holder[0], number: 0 }, { name: holder[1], number: 0 }]);
        return p;
    }, []);
}
var getCSV = function (url, done) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url);
    req.onload = function () { return done(null, req.response); }
    req.onerror = function () { return done(req.statusText, req.response); }
    req.send();
}

parse("http://www.sfu.ca/~djr7/data/Round3.csv");
```

It returns the following data (but as an array of arrays of objects):

```
/*
        Saber (Fate/Stay Night UBW) 1031 Rin (Fate/Stay Night UBW) 658
        Akame (Akame ga Kill!) 1282 Ema (Shirobako) 426
        Kurumi (Date A Live) 1114 Esdeath (Akame ga Kill!) 602
        Tachibana (Nisekoi) 885 Yuuki (Sword Art Online 2) 854
        Stephanie (No Game No Life) 903 Tsugumi (Nisekoi) 834
        Rikka (Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Ren) 0 Sinon (Sword Art Online 2) 1018
*/
```